# How to raise sql query for trigger after update and get old and updated values?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, interface, oracle-apps

How can I get old and newly updated values after update trigger???

Please help me guys.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, if the trigger is set with the `FOR EACH ROW` option.

By default, new values are referenced by `:new.column_name` and old values by `:old.column_name`, but those aliases can be changed with the `REFERENCING` keyword. See [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374) for more details.